# java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: getLong

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I get data from Oracle, using JDBC and `ojdbc7.jar` library. My `dataSource`:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="${oracle.url}"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="username" value="${oracle.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${oracle.password}"/>
        <property name="maxTotal" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="-1"/>
    </bean>
```

My code:

```
public List<Link> getTerminalDevices(final int numbersMonths, final Long initServiceId, final List<Long> switchableServices) throws Exception {
        final List<Link> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (final Connection cnn = myDataSource.getConnection();
             final OracleCallableStatement stm = cnn.prepareCall(sql).unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class)) {
            stm.setPlsqlIndexTable(1, switchableServices.toArray(), switchableServices.size(), switchableServices.size(), OracleTypes.BIGINT, 0);
            stm.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            stm.setLong(3, initServiceId);
            stm.setInt(4, numbersMonths);
            stm.execute();

            try (final ResultSet rs = stm.getCursor(2)) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    result.add(new Link()
                            .id(rs.getLong(1))
                            .name(rs.getString(2))
                            .date(rs.getTimestamp(3)));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**This code run in 5 Threads.** Sometimes, once from a time I have an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: getLong
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:539) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
```

The error **is not constant**, and manifests itself under unclear conditions.

What's wrong? I don't understand this error, I correctly process connections, I'm using try-with resources. **I can't close resultset!**

**UPDATE**:

I conducted an investigation and found that the problem in this line:

`final OracleCallableStatement stm = cnn.prepareCall(sql).unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class)`

If I make like this:

```
 try (final Connection cnn = oracleDatasource.getConnection();
             final CallableStatement originalCs = cnn.prepareCall(sql)) {

            OracleCallableStatement stm;
            if (originalCs instanceof OracleCallableStatement) {
                stm = (OracleCallableStatement) originalCs;
            } else {
                DelegatingCallableStatement tomcatCs = (DelegatingCallableStatement) originalCs;
                stm = (OracleCallableStatement) tomcatCs.getInnermostDelegate();
            }
```

It,s work correct. **Who has any thoughts on this?** Why `unwrap` don't work correctly?

Comment: I think that the problem is, that you pass the cursor from the database to java and the database somehow comes to the conclusion that the cursor is no longer needed and therefore closes the cursor. Perhaps you should convert your database routine into a pipelined function and pass the data to java instead of the cursor...

Comment: Can I see somewhere that the database has closed the cursor?

Comment: I'm not sure how todo this, but one other thing that you can test is, if the Resultset in different threads point to the same object. Might be that the driver class reuses the cursor if the sql-statement is the same...

Comment: `if the Resultset in different threads point to the same object`, Does this mean that they will have the same hash code?

Comment: Given your last edit, the problem is probably one of garbage collection: you lost the reference to the proxy/wrapper statement object, and when that was reclaimed by the garbage collector, it closed the underlying statement. Unwrap will probably work fine, as long as you keep a reference to the statement returned from `cnn.prepareCall(sql)`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, How can I verify that I have lost the reference to the proxy / wrapper statement object? It turns out that I would have to get a `NullPointerException` if the link was killed by the garbage collector? Why I not have NPE?

Comment: @All_Safe Your code loses the reference to the proxy when you do `cnn.prepareCall(sql).unwrap`. The call to `cnn.prepareCall` returns a proxy object, as you don't store it in a local variable, you hold no reference. Depending on the exact implementation this can cause the proxy to be garbage collected, which may trigger additional cleanup (eg closing the wrapped statement). Why do you think that would trigger a `NullPointerException`, it wouldn't. If you store `originalCs` like in your second code and only then use `unwrap`, I'd expect it to work just fine.